# Ajax sometimes works with post and sometimes works with get

Tags: php, ajax, post, get

I know this may look strange but it happened to me many times.
I'm building a website, and everytime I use ajax, i choose POST as method, and to call datas in php file I use $_POST.
At first it works... but after a few days, all scripts using ajax don't work anymore, then I tried to remplace $_POST to $_GET, but ajax method is still always POST.
and after some days again scripts don't work and i remplace get to post... I don't want to get these errors again so I want to know why i had to remplace those methodes in php files.

this is example of the JS code

```
$(".add-category").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $(".cats").append('<div class="load" style="margin:auto"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>');
    $.ajax({
        method : "POST",
        url : $this.data("url"),
        data : {
            cat : $this.prev().val()
        },
            success : function(data){
        $('.load').remove();
        $(".cats").append(data);
        }
    });
});
```

and this is its php file

```
<?php
require_once "../../core/Database.php";
require_once "../../core/functions.php";
Database::connect();

if(isset($_GET["cat"]) && strlen($_GET["cat"]) > 0 ){
    Database::query("INSERT INTO categories(title_category) VALUES(?)",[$_GET["cat"]]);
    $req = Database::query("SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY id_category DESC");
    $cat = $req->fetch();
echo '
    <div class="gray cat">'.$cat->title_category.'
        <a href="" class="red add-category" data-url="'.getLink("index",["page"=>"delete-category","id"=>$cat->id_category]).'"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
    </div>
';
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Post (heh, no pun intended) your PHP and JS code here and we'll take a look - if you click the edit button under your question you can upload your code there.

Comment: @ScottMcGready i've edited the question, thanks for answering

Comment: FYI your PHP script seems to be checking for `$_GET` params... not `$_POST` params...

Comment: @ScottMcGready i put GET because POST didn't work, and GET worked

Comment: have you in the `url` something like `aphpfile.php?cat=whatever`

Comment: @moskito-x no, getAbsPath() function returns the absolute path of the file

Comment: absolute path is OK . But have you added content to the path?

Comment: @moskito-x if you mean, by content to the path, something like &id=...., no I didn't, getAbsPath return a link like /folder/folder/file.php

Comment: echo or allert the `url`

Comment: @moskito-x i can see the url in source code... it is /admin/app/add-category.php